# SQL query using both LIKE and IN with wild cards

Tags: sql, select

I have a database table where users can filter a single column using a large number of variables and currently my sql query strings look something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE '%APPLE%'
AND COLUMN1 LIKE '%ORANGE%'
AND COLUMN1 LIKE '%GRAPE%'
AND COLUMN1 LIKE '%LEMON%'
AND COLUMN1 LIKE '%LIME%'
AND COLUMN1 LIKE '%TOMATO%'
AND COLUMN1 LIKE '%POTATO%'
...
```

which becomes a pain to implement especially if I am using a parameterized query string in a table adapter to create fill and get methods that end up having 20 parameters.

Is there any better way of doing this (like using the IN command so I only need one parameter)?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387612/how-can-i-introduce-multiple-conditions-in-like-operator - @BillKarwin has a good answer there (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1387797/1073107) that I've used to do something similar.

Comment: @Tony - you have to be more specific: "users can filter a single column using a large number of variables" - which variables ? please provide a few examples for a valid input as well

Comment: Just updated the problem to make it more clear

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? If you're searching a column for words, you may want to consider a Fulltext Index.

Comment: @JamieSee How could I have forgotten! Of course, CONTAINS with a FullText Index would be very useful here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Comment: @JamieSee Okay, suppose the table is a list of all produce that I sell, and it includes entries like green apple, red apple, blood orange, vine tomato... etc and I want to filter ALL the oranges, apples, tomatoes.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE CONTAINS(Column1, ' Oranges OR Apples OR Tomatoes')` would bring back all the columns that contain any of those words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Microsoft SQL server you should look at [Full-Text Search (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or [Full-Text Search (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) if you're using SQL 2012. There are a number of ways to do searches for words more effectively than LIKE matching.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `regular expressions` will help you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE '%[a-z]%'
```

If you use `sql-server` try `CONTAINS`

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CONTAINS(COLUMN1, 'APPLE AND ORANGE')
```

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/krishnasarala/creating-full-text-index-in-sql-server/) you can find more information.

Comment: That's not equivalent: his query will catch alpha-numeric values, for example, while your regex won't.