# How to search multiple strings or chars in a field in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using sql server and i have a table which have two fields

1. Name
2. Description

I want to select all those rows which contains following strings

('$','%' , 'ac cd' , 'hjd oih')

I am using it like this

```
select Name , description from table_name 
where Description like any (' %$%',' %[%]%','%ac cd%' , '%hjd oih%')
```

now its giving error when i run this

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'any'.
```

thanks ,

Comment: Please check similar question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `multiple patterns` to search then its better to create a `derived table` or `temporary table` to store the `patterns`

```
DECLARE @patterns TABLE  (
pattern VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO @patterns VALUES ('%$%'), ('%[%]%'), ('%ac cd%');

SELECT a.* FROM table_name a JOIN @patterns p ON (a.Description LIKE p.pattern);
```

If you have multiple columns to compare just add expression in the `ON` clause

```
SELECT a.* FROM table_name a JOIN @patterns p ON (a.Description LIKE p.pattern)
OR (a.Column2 like p.pattern);
```

**Updated: Using View**

```
CREATE VIEW PatternSearch
AS
 WITH Patterns (Patterns)
  AS
  (
     Select  '%Tool%'
     union all
     Select '%Sale%'
     union all
     Select  '%ac cd%'
  )
   SELECT a.* FROM table_name a JOIN Patterns p ON (a.Description LIKE p.pattern)

GO
```

Not tested but you can do like this

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387612/how-can-i-introduce-multiple-conditions-in-like-operator)

Comment: but what if want to do the same thing in a sql view . because i tried but its giving error

Comment: If you are doing it in View then  i think you need to use CTE

Comment: This one uses UNION instead of JOIN. (I like the JOIN better...) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387612/how-can-i-introduce-multiple-conditions-in-like-operator?lq=1