# dplyr multiple inputs from Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I have a Shiny app that takes input from radio button and then use that to perform filter to the data frame using `dplyr` in the server side. It works, but now I want to expand it to take multiple inputs to filter, and I have no idea how to do it.

To illustrate, it's something like this in `ui.R`

```
radioButtons(
  inputId = "selectPrincipal",
  choices = c("a", "b", "c")
)
```

And selection in `server.R` like this

```
output$PrincipalValue <- renderText({
  x <- df %>%
    filter(Principal==input$selectPrincipal) %>%
    summarize(total=sum(Value))
  prettyNum(x$total, big.mark=",")
})
```

`df` would contain something like this

```
> df
Source: local data frame [10 x 2]

   Principal Value
1          a     4
2          a     1
3          a     1
4          a     3
5          b     4
6          b     2
7          b     2
8          b     3
9          c     2
10         c     1
```

The above set up works. Now say I want to introduce a new radio button selection called "All". What value should I pass to `filter(Principal==` in `server.R` above? Is there a wild card in `dplyr` to filter keeping all? Or is there another approach equivalent to concatenating all the values (I can't figure out the syntax though)?

In a way I guess [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187858/rodbc-multiple-inputs-from-shiny) is asking the same as this one on RODBC multiple inputs from shiny, but am wondering if there is a different approach for `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Principal == input$selectPrincipal | input$selectPrincipal == "All"
```