# How to search with keywords? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I was wondering how to generate a search SQL query for keywords:

### I know:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword LIKE %keyword%;
```

But how to work with multiple keywords.

I hope that makes sense...

Comment: try `WHERE keyword LIKE %keyword% or keyword LIKE %keyword2% or ..` change or to and if you want to match all keywords

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387612/how-can-i-introduce-multiple-conditions-in-like-operator

Comment: It depends what type of search you want.

Comment: This may help too http://anthonykinson.co.uk/programing-internet/568_making-mysql-searches-relevant

Comment: Btw your query will fail. You have to wrap %keyword% in quotes: ... LIKE "%keyword%"

Comment: @bksi keywords search like search engines do.

Comment: There are different algorithms for search. You can use full text search integrated in mysql and sort by relevance explained here (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or simple search you explain in your question

Comment: Searching with wildcards on both sides can become quite inefficient when dealing with large data sets, even if the field is indexed.  You may want to look into [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) searching in MySQL.  In version 5.5 and below you can only use them with MyISAM tables, in 5.6+ you can use them in InnoDB tables as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with below codes:

You can use FULL TEXT SEARCH

```
SELECT col1 FROM table_name
WHERE MATCH (col1, col2, col3)
AGAINST ('keywords');
```

For this, you need to apply fulltext index on columns in which you want to search.

You can use `IN` operator too like -

```
SELECT col1 FROM table_name
WHERE col1 IN (keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table`
WHERE keyword LIKE '%1%'
OR keyword LIKE '%2%'
OR keyword LIKE '%3%'
```

If I understand you right, this is what you're looking for

Comment: I think OP needs full text search

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of percent signs and [underscore wildcards](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/wildcards-like-operator/wildcards-underscore.php)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword LIKE "%keywordA_keywordB%";
```

Or use CONTAINS and do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE keyword CONTAINS "%keywordA%" AND keyword CONTAINS "%keywordB%";
```