# How do you write a query with "multiple string/substring matching"?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

How do you write a query with "multiple string/substring matching"?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE ('%BD%','%IND%','%PK%','%USA%')
```

Comment: Do you want to match any of the strings, or any combination of these strings in the columns? Also, what DBMS are you using - MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of mysql -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172195/mysql-like-multiple-values and oracle - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387612/how-can-i-introduce-multiple-conditions-in-like-operator

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from table where column like '%BD%' or column like '%IND%'or column like'%PK%' or column like'%USA%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table 
 where regexp_like(column,'BD|IND|PK')
```