# How to select 3 specific pattern in column using SQL? What is wrong with my code?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName LIKE ('%aa%','%bb%','%cc%');
```

Comment: Try this- [Introduce-multiple-conditions-in-like-operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387612/how-can-i-introduce-multiple-conditions-in-like-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM Customers 
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%aa%' OR CustomerName LIKE '%bb%' OR CustomerName LIKE '%cc%';
```

`LIKE` does not work the same as `IN` where you can list a set of possibilities to match against. You have to use an `OR` between `LIKE` statements to match multiple patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting your conditions like this

```
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%aa%' OR CustomerName LIKE '%bb%' OR  CustomerName LIKE '%cc%'
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%aa%' OR CustomerName LIKE '%bb%' OR CustomerName LIKE '%cc%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code

SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE
instr(CustomerName,'aa')>0 or instr(CustomerName,'bb')>0 or instr(CustomerName,'cc')>0

However this is working in oracle 11G, Please check the compatibility as well