# Why SQL query return additional rows when using multiple OR condition?

Tags: sql

Hello I have Filter option in my program.[image]

When i use an single option like when i filter only by **STATUS=SCHEDULED** i get the correct list as shown bellow 
[image]

But when i give multiple condition then the SQl query returns more additional rows irrelevant to the date. like bellow

[image]

i am trying to filter the order with **STATUS=SCHEDULED** and **CUSTOMER ID=87**.

I took reference from [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387612/how-can-i-introduce-multiple-conditions-in-like-operator)
[here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-server)

And bellow is my SQL query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    workforce_customerorder
WHERE
    ORDER_ID LIKE '$sOrder'
UNION
SELECT
    *
FROM
    workforce_customerorder
WHERE
    CUSTOMER_ID LIKE '%$sCustomerID%'
UNION
SELECT
    *
FROM
    workforce_customerorder
WHERE
    AGENT_NUMBER LIKE '%$sAgentNumber%'
UNION
SELECT
    *
FROM
    workforce_customerorder
WHERE
STATUS LIKE
    '$sStatus'
UNION
SELECT
    *
FROM
    workforce_customerorder
WHERE
    GST_NUMBER LIKE '$sGST'
UNION
SELECT
    *
FROM
    workforce_customerorder
WHERE
    DATE(ORDER_DATE) BETWEEN '$sOrderDateFrom' AND '$sOrderDateTo'
```

I need the best SQl query. Thanks in advance

Ok After I tried using AND this what i got

[image]

Comment: You don't need all those unions, you could just use a single query with a `WHERE` clause containing the conditions.  Also note that `UNION` will remove duplicates; this could have something to do with your complaint about not seeing the correct number of records in the result set.

Comment: On the 3rd picture what i tried to filter the row with customerID  which has the status as SCHEDULED  but i got the row with STATUS as OPEN which i dont need

Comment: What are the customerIDs of the irrelevant rows?

Comment: i have the Customer ID= 87 and its Status = SCHEDULED  and i want only the row with Customer ID= 87 and its Status = SCHEDULED but im am getting Customer ID= 87 and its Status = OPEN which i do not need

Comment: Its because UNION works like OR.  I would remove the condition on date range search when testing the suggested answers below (using AND instead UNION).

Comment: Please check the last image which i added

Comment: Why i am getting down votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok finally i found the solution

```
     $query_order_id  = ($sOrder  != "") ? " AND (ORDER_ID LIKE '$sOrder') " : "";
    $query_customer_id = ($sCustomerID  != "") ? " AND (CUSTOMER_ID LIKE '%".$sCustomerID."' OR '".$sCustomerID."' IS NULL) " : "";
    $query_sAgentNumber =   ($sAgentNumber  != "") ? " AND (AGENT_NUMBER LIKE '%".$sAgentNumber."%' OR '".$sAgentNumber."' IS NULL) " : "";
    $query_sStatus =   ($sStatus  != "") ? " AND (STATUS LIKE '%".$sStatus."%' OR '".$sStatus."' IS NULL) " : "";
    $query_sGST =   ($sGST  != "") ? " AND (GST_NUMBER LIKE '%".$sGST."%' OR '".$sGST."' IS NULL) " : "";
    $query_sOrderDateFrom = ($sOrderDateFrom != "") ? " AND (DATE(ORDER_DATE) BETWEEN COALESCE('$sOrderDateFrom', ORDER_DATE) AND COALESCE('$sOrderDateTo', ORDER_DATE)) " : "";
//sql query here

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM workforce_customerorder where ORDER_ID IS NOT NULL".$query_order_id.$query_customer_id.$query_sAgentNumber.$query_sStatus.$query_sGST.$query_sOrderDateFrom;
    }
```

It is same as what @Caleth showed but the one which matched exactly is by applying ternary operator before passing the variable to SQL query. Thank you every one you answers...

Answer (score 2):

You should have just one query, with a WHERE clause that performs the filtering on only the columns that are set

```
SELECT *
FROM workforce_customerorder
WHERE
    (ORDER_ID = COALESCE('$sOrder', ORDER_ID)) AND
    (CUSTOMER_ID LIKE '%$sCustomerID%' OR '$sCustomerID' IS NULL) AND
    (AGENT_NUMBER LIKE '%$sAgentNumber%' OR '$sAgentNumber' IS NULL) AND
    (STATUS = COALESCE('$sStatus', STATUS)) AND
    (GST_NUMBER = COALESCE('$sGST', GST_NUMBER)) AND
    (DATE(ORDER_DATE) BETWEEN COALESCE('$sOrderDateFrom', ORDER_DATE) AND COALESCE('$sOrderDateTo', ORDER_DATE))
```

Note that `LIKE` without a wildcard is equivalent to `=`. I find it clearer to specify which are exact matches and which are sub-matches with different syntaxes.

Comment: i am getting error as unexpected token near CUSTOMER_ID,AGENT_ID

Comment: I may have gotten the syntax wrong for `'%' + COALESCE('$sCustomerID', CUSTOMER_ID)) + '%'`

Comment: Updated. Is the `LIKE` really necessary?

Comment: ok i do not know much about sql i just know the very basics can u provide me the sql query just to filter rows as i shown in the picture i have just added multiple conditions for filtering i may or may not fill all the conditions necessarily i will vary on situations. Like i have option to filter by DATE, ORDER ID, CUSTOMER ID, STATUS and GST NUMBER some time i may filter using status so the other values will be passed as null so what is best query needed for this condition

Comment: yes i just pass only the status values and i got 0 results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162527/discussion-between-vignesh-and-caleth).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `UNION`. You should be using `AND` in a single `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior you are witnessing is due to use of `UNION`, Omit `UNION` and use `AND` like:

```
SELECT  * FROM  workforce_customerorder
WHERE
    ORDER_ID LIKE '$sOrder'
AND
    CUSTOMER_ID LIKE '%$sCustomerID%'
AND
    AGENT_NUMBER LIKE '%$sAgentNumber%'
....
```

When using `UNION` although one of the subsets may be  empty you get the results from all other non empty subsets

Comment: I used the above query and i return 0 result when i filter by status @apomene

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a UNION that means give me anything in either of these sets, or in both. Try using just AND if you want two+ conditions to be true

Answer (score 0):

Using `UNION`, you merge your columns. Because you use the same data table in your unions, you have the same column multiple times. You should use `AND` instead in the `WHERE`statement. Below is the corrected query.

```
SELECT *
FROM workforce_customerorder
WHERE
    ORDER_ID LIKE '$sOrder'
        AND CUSTOMER_ID LIKE '%$sCustomerID%'
        AND AGENT_NUMBER LIKE '%$sAgentNumber%'
        AND STATUS LIKE '$sStatus'
        AND GST_NUMBER LIKE '$sGST'
        AND DATE(ORDER_DATE) BETWEEN '$sOrderDateFrom' AND '$sOrderDateTo'
```

Comment: @Vignesh - you probably need to exclude conditions on fields, not filled on web form.

Comment: Ok about this query what happens when one or more condition is nul

Comment: An empty field will result in : if the condition have a '%' in the LIKE expression it will be omitted and the output will be the matching rows to the other conditions. Else, if it doesn't contain a '%' it won't return anything.

Comment: hey i have added the picture of the query which u suggested

Comment: Are you coding your site with PHP ? Then you can set a default value to your variable instead of NULL.

Comment: something along the lines of `WHERE (ORDER_ID = COALESCE('$sOrder', ORDER_ID)) AND ...`, so that you have vacuously true parts of your WHERE clause when a parameter is null

Comment: yes im using php but still i just can not get it, i am saying i have multiple filter options i may pass many value or i may just pass only single value  but why its not returning any result even when i mention those values with null

Comment: Do you have some data in your table ? Then can you try filling all fields of the form and submit to see if you got some data ?